# Map Folder in war file to root path of aws server via Elastic Beanstalk custom apache config file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a folder named `dist`containing an angular2 frontend for my spring boot/jhipster gradle app. 
Now I try to upload the war file containing backend and frontend to aws via elastic beanstalk war upload (web frontend).

I've set a custom configuration file - `xx-tomcat-settings.config` into .ebextensions folder. With the following content according to [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html), it works:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /dist : dist
```

This maps my dist folder to `[myUrl]/dist`, which works. I can call `http://***/dist/my.js` and it shows me the contents.
**But**, because of the path of the frontendassets, I actually want to map `/dist` to `/`. So I changed my custom config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    / : dist
```

With this config file, it seems nothing gets mapped. I can't get `http://***/dist/my.js` or `http://***/my.js`

So my question is: How to correctly reference root folder in the config file? Or, if this is not possible, is there a good alternative way to achieve the mapping?

I looked via `jar -tf my.war`if the war file is correct, which it is. Now I am out of ideas, beaing relatively new to aws/eb. I haven't found something in the aws support forums or docs, so...

Thanks in advance!